# Can all oxygen be provided cutaneous in humans?

Tags: respiration

What partial pressure of oxygen is needed on the skin to completely replace the lungs function as oxygen receivers? Respiration has other functions too. I am only asking about oxygen intake.

Oxygenation through the skin could eventually be used against ischaemia like gangrene and covid clotting.

The skin might eventually be kept wet to improve oxygen diffusion through the skin, as this is the case with animals.

In normal conditions cutaneous respiration is [1-2% in humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaneous_respiration#Mammals). This means that with an atmosphere of close to 100 % oxygen and pressure of 10 bar, 50-100 % of a humans oxygen intake can be through cutaneous respiration.